# Taking photos, checking GPS and another things on Android using HTML 5 app?

Tags: android, html, mobile, web

It is possible to make fully functional app for android using HTML and Javascript? 
If android browser allows Web pages to use camera, GPS, access to gallery etc? 
I want to make cross platform app (for Android, iPhone and windows phone) but I don't have time to learn how to make apps for them. 
I heard about phone.js, but when I check it once, it demanded to pay. It wasn't for my budget ;P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try out http://phonegap.com and http://www.appcelerator.com/titanium/

A comparison of the two can be found here:
http://developer.appcelerator.com/blog/2012/05/comparing-titanium-and-phonegap.html

Comment: Is phonegap completely free? I mean: can I put my app for example to Google play and earn money without paying for phonegap?

Comment: Yes, it is completely free.
Adobe do offer a build service, so you don't need to mess around with the SDK's, called Phonegap Build - https://build.phonegap.com/

Even with that you get 1 free project.